# Disabling the "Chosen option is not enabled" message in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I am developing an Eclipse plugin. I disable a menu item using the isEnabled() method in its handler class. As I run the plugin and click on it, it shows that the **chosen option is not currently available**. I want to disable this message, or at least change it. Is there any way?

Comment: You have mentioned two different messages 'The chosen operation is not currently available' and 'The chosen operation is not enabled', which one is it? They mean different things. However neither of them can be overridden.

Comment: The message is "The chosen option is not enabled". Is there no way I can disable this message from popping-up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not override `isEnabled`.

Instead call `setBaseEnabled(boolean)` to enable / disable the handler. This will fire an event for the handler enablement which should stop the menu item from being clickable so you won't get this message.